# Setting up a server for a meteor.js application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, meteor, server, ubuntu-14.04

I am attempting to deploy my meteor application on aws beanstalk (Ubuntu 14.04) without the use of a deployment package.

Reason being, I want to get a rounded knowledge as to how the files will be structured on aws for my learning process and what I need to do and think about.

I am attempting to set-up/install all relevant programs on aws for my application to function as it does so nicely on my local server.

Can anyone list the all the programs that I must install (as well as node.js meteor js) and in what order.

Eg. Do I need to install opensll? Typically what is the first thing to think about when setting up a server?

I am happy for people to add to the list.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

See the "Deploying on your own infrastructure" section of the docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deploying

Notably, you do not need to install Meteor to run it on your server. All you need is an installed node.js and a MongoDB server to connect to (usually it is a good idea to buy database hosting from somebody that will provide support and backups).

Copied from there (but I would suggest future people go directly to the docs instead, to see the most up to date info):

> You can also run your application on your own infrastructure or any hosting provider that can run Node.js apps.
>
> To get started, run

```
$ meteor build my_directory
```

> This command will generate a fully-contained Node.js application in the form of a tarball. To run this application, you need to provide Node.js 0.10 and a MongoDB server. (The current release of Meteor has been tested with Node 0.10.33.) You can then run the application by invoking node, specifying the HTTP port for the application to listen on, and the MongoDB endpoint.

```
$ cd my_directory
$ (cd programs/server && npm install)
$ PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp node main.js
```

> Some packages might require other environment variables. For example, the email package requires a MAIL_URL environment variable.

Comment: I am using amazons free tier ubuntu. It is a blank slate. What enables a server to run node js apps? Is it the set up they have prepared for it? 

Thank you for helping and pardon the trivial questions. I am sourcing the information that you have provided and more.